# How to reuse existing variable in TensorFlow when dtypes differ?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Minimal code example:

```
with tf.variable_scope("initializer_test"):
    s = tf.get_variable("scalar", initializer=tf.constant(2)) 

with tf.variable_scope("initializer_test", reuse=True):
    s = tf.get_variable("scalar")
# ValueError: Trying to share variable initializer_test/scalar, but specified dtype float32 and found dtype int32_ref.
```

---

My solution:

Just reading the error message gives an easy solution:

```
with tf.variable_scope("initializer_test"):
    s = tf.get_variable("scalar", initializer=tf.constant(2)) 

with tf.variable_scope("initializer_test", reuse=True):
    s = tf.get_variable("scalar", dtype=tf.int32) # Just add the required dtype
```

Is there a better way to do this? I would prefer to not have to (look at the error message to find out the dtype) or (manually set the dtype for `s` the first time I declare it).

Answer (score 0):

Adds `AUTO_REUSE` as a reuse mode to variable scopes. This mode modifies the behavior of `get_variable()` to create requested variables if they do not exist or return them if they do exist.

It is now possible to write the following code:

```
def call_f():
    with tf.variable_scope("initializer_test", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        v = tf.get_variable("scalar", initializer=tf.constant(2))
    return v

v1 = call_f()  # Creates v.
v2 = call_f()  # Gets the same, existing v.

print(v1)
print(v2)
```

output:

```
<tf.Variable 'initializer_test/scalar:0' shape=() dtype=int32, numpy=2>
<tf.Variable 'initializer_test/scalar:0' shape=() dtype=int32, numpy=2>
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it doesn't seem to work. What version is your TensorFlow? I suspect that's probably my issue...

Comment: my tensorflow version is '1.12.0'